# How to affect the directive children using @HostBinding?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-directive

I'm implementing a bootsrap's single button dropdown ([docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/dropdowns/#single-button)).

In order to make it to be "open", it must add a `show` class to main `<div>` and to the `<ul>`.

This is closed:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
      Manage (Using Directive) <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a style="cursor: pointer;">Edit </a></li>
    <li><a style="cursor: pointer;">Delete </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is open:

```
<div class="btn-group show">
  <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
      Manage (Using Directive) <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu show">
    <li><a style="cursor: pointer;">Edit </a></li>
    <li><a style="cursor: pointer;">Delete </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

I'm trying to make it work as a directive with:

```
<div class="btn-group" appDropdown>
  <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
      Manage (Using Directive) <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a style="cursor: pointer;">Edit </a></li>
    <li><a style="cursor: pointer;">Delete </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the dropdown.directive.ts:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropdown]'
})
export class DropdownDirective {
  @HostBinding('class.show') isOpen = false;

  @HostListener('click') toggleOpen() {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }
}
```

This way I'm only able to add the `show` class to the `<div>` without adding it to the `<ul>`,
**Is there a way to affect the directive children**?

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-99qqnp?file=src/app/app.component.html)

This is a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42715318/can-i-access-child-elements-within-a-directive-in-angular2), but it does not mention any @HostBinding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this post when I was looking for the answer to the same question. I solved the issue myself using ElementRef. I'm fairly new to Angular but coming from a React background I thought if the 'Ref' in element ref is similar to Refs in React then it should have HTML attributes & properties, specifically querySelector.

So if anyone else is stumped on this, this can serve as a solution.

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropdown]',
})
export class DropdownDirective {
  constructor(private dropdownRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {}

  @HostListener('click') toggleOpen = () => {
    this.dropdownRef.nativeElement
      .querySelector('div')
      .classList.toggle('hidden');
  };
}
```